# Does Swift uses static or dynamic scoping?

Tags: swift, dynamic, scope, static

I'm reading an article that saying that Swift uses either static or dynamic scoping? Can you enlighten me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Static scope (or Lexical scope), definition of a variable is resolve by searching its containing block or function. If that fails, then search the outer containing block and so on. For example:

```
var a = 10, b = 20
func division() {
    var a = 5
        do {
           var c = b / a
           print(c)
        }
} /// OUTPUT: 4
```

so the output is 4 because when the function is called, it initialize the variable a to 5 and then procede with the do statement. When the do statement is executed it does an operation with the variables b and a so it looks for those values. Following the definition of static scope or lexical scope it search between its curly braces, nothing is there so it move to the next scope, outer scope and it found the value of variable a so it choses the value 5 for a then since it doesn't find a value for variable b it goes to the global scope and find the value of variable b. so it divide b by a (20/5) and the result is 4.
In conclusion due to this example the Swift Programming Language use Static Scope. I'm not sure if there is a way to make it support Dynamic also. I hope this help.